# Каково дословное значение выражения "куда ни шло"?

Tags: фразеология

**Это ещё куда ни шло...**

Такое выражение применяется в языке часто, и значение его известно, но **почему используется именно такая формулировка?**

Можно ли этот краткий вариант заменить полной фразой?

Из словаря:

КУДА НИ ШЛО.  разг. выражает степень удовлетворения чем-нибудь, граничащую с неудовлетворением: кое-как, как-нибудь.

Пример:  В цирке это **куда ни шло** ― публика настроена демократически и ценит буффонаду. [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы (я чуть позже напишу свой комментарий). И всем самого счастливого и доброго Нового года

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что **каждое фразеологическое сочетание поддается дословной расшифровке.** Другими словами, есть такой «виртуальный фразеологический словарь», из которого мы могли бы получать  ответы на все наши вопросы (что-то вроде лингвистического отдела  всеобщего информационного поля, **если, конечно,  такое существует**). (Иначе говоря, если объяснения нет, то это значит, что мы его просто еще не нашли).

**Как научиться им пользоваться?** Один из методов известен (с его помощью Менделеев открыл свою периодическую таблицу): надо сосредоточиться, сконцентрировать внимание и долго-долго думать над проблемой, прислушиваясь к звучанию слов.

Вот я и попыталась это сделать.  Сначала просто задала себе вопрос, потом поискала в Сети, но ответа не получила.  Но ведь ответ-то есть.

Куда ни шло…    Когда-то  это было сказано впервые, но это только первая часть высказывания. Может быть, **«куда ни шло, везде подошло»?** То есть такая идея **универсально**сти.

Когда  трудно найти выход из ситуации, можно применить какое-нибудь универсальное средство. Конечно, оно не лучшее, но это уже хотя бы что-то. Другие варианты совсем не подходят, а это ещё «куда ни шло».

Кстати, здесь возможна и другая форма с частицей НЕ (форма риторического вопроса): **это  куда не шло (может, и нам подойдет).** Но закрепилась форма написания с  частицей НИ.

**Из синонимического ряда, как мне кажется,   подходит только оборот «это еще туда-сюда».** Тоже своеобразная загадка.

**Прямое значение**: ходить туда-сюда, взад-вперед. **Переносное значение:** увиливать от ответа, оправдываться, уговаривать (я туда-сюда, а он  не соглашается).  **А значение минимальной удовлетворенности** (= более или менее сносно) здесь откуда? Например: «Старая дама два первых роббера играла еще туда-сюда» (Куприн). Может быть, и здесь речь идет о том же  **расхожем варианте,  и туда и сюда подходящем?**

РАСХОЖИЙ, 2. Предназначенный для повседневного употребления, пользования; будничный, каждодневный.  3. Неодобр. Общеизвестный, широко распространённый; банальный.

Итак,  «это еще куда ни шло, это еще туда-сюда»  –  **это оценка универсального, расхожего варианта, только минимально нас удовлетворяющего.**

Вот такая версия ответа, но это только версия.

Comment: Хотел задать этот вопрос, но нашёл ваш вопрос и ответ. У меня были похожие догадки, и я думаю, что вы правы. «Куда ни шло», скорей всего, изначально значило «куда не подходило». Т. е. это был какой-то вариант, который успешно применялся в ряде ситуаций в прошлом. Например, решали, как поступить и говорили что-то вроде: вот этот вариант сработал и в этой, и в этой ситуации, и не было ситуации, чтоб это не сработало — куда это не шло (не подходило), давай и сейчас так поступим. (1/2)

Comment: Потом, я думаю, значение сместилось на какой-то заурядный, заезженный вариант, т. е. ничего нового, ничего выдающегося, но сойдёт. А потом уже из этого значения, наверное, вытекло значение, как вы выразились, «минимальной удовлетворённости». Я проголосовал за ваш ответ. (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе предположить, что есть общее с наречием как-нибудь. "Как бы ни было", "куда бы ни шло" — нас это более или менее устроит.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у "куда бы ни шло" и "куда ни шло" разные значения. Куда бы ни шло - это все равно куда, то есть подойдет любой вариант. А здесь обозначен вариант не из лучших, но допустимый. У меня есть идея ответа, но я в ней не уверена, хотелось бы сначала услышать другие мнения

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите мой комментарий  к вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447340/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5  А то его все решительно игнорировали, и я стала сомневаться в разумности мною сказанного.

Answer (score 1):

Сносно, более-менее,  терпимо - эти наречия, а так же глаголы - сойдёт, сгодится, - на мой взгляд, по смыслу здесь вполне подойдут.  Фразой заменить можно, только зачем? Ведь подобные выражения для того и существуют,  чтобы ёмко,  но кратко выразить своё отношение к событию.  Пример приведу такой: " Если у исполнителя нет яркого имени, я могу это понять(взамен" это ещё куда ни шло"),  но у него и голоса нет!"  Сравните: "Если у исполнителя нет яркого имени, это терпимо(ещё сойдёт), но у него и голоса нет!"

Comment: *Фразой заменить можно, только зачем?* — предлагаете в приказном порядке внедрить "Basic Russian"? Не согласен, что слова "сгодится" и т.п. всегда подойдут по смыслу.

Comment: Нет, не предлагаю. Задаюсь вопросом.  В том и дело, что не всегда по смыслу подходит только одно слово, для того и появляются эти выражения,  чтобы существовала возможность кратко передавать мысль, не выстраивая длинные фразы.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, что нигде не удаётся обнаружить попыток проследить происхождение этого выражения. Вижу одно простое объяснение: это невозможно. Подробный семантический анализ данной *уступительной конструкции* есть в монографии Апресяна "Языковая картина мира и системная лексикография". Там рассматривается синонимичный ряд: *пускай бы, добро бы, ладно бы, **куда ни шло**, ещё туда-сюда*. "Пускай бы" уже устарело; "добро бы" является уходящим, а в некоторых ситуациях также устаревшим; "ладно бы" — современное, почти синонимичное им выражение, последние два также являются современными аналогами. Не во всех случаях эти выражения взаимозаменяемы.

Я думаю, что "куда ни шло" образовано по типичной фразеобразовательной модели, которую Апресян называет "к-местоимение + ни ..." (под к-местоимениями здесь понимаются относительные местоимения типа *кто, что, сколько* и пр.). Примеры: *как ни крути, куда ни глянь, сколько ни ищи, что ни делай* и т.п. Слово "шло" в этой конструкции может быть семантически связано со значением "подходить, соответствовать". С другой стороны, само выражение "куда ни шло" могло быть образовано в виде отрицания какого-то другого выражения, типа "ни в какие ворота не лезет".

Выскажу отдельно свою гипотезу появления и закрепления в языке подобных выражений. Подобные новые выражения могут ситуативно возникать в больших количествах для схожих значений, но в языке закрепляются только наиболее удачные, которые занимают определённую (не очень узкую) нишу в "семантическом поле" и являются достаточно гибкими для самого разнообразного употребления. Поэтому более важным мне представляется вопрос не о том, как возник фразеологизм, а почему он закрепился в языке (особенно в отношении современного языка).

Comment: А Вам дополнительное спасибо за доброе внимание к моим вопросам и моим проблемам. С Новым годом!

Comment: И Вас с Новым Годом! :)