# Запятая в предложении "Отдай(,) и ты получишь все"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

В каком варианте предложения правильно стоит запятая?
1. Отдай, и ты получишь все.
2. Отдай и ты получишь все.

Если можно, объясните, почему так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно (запятая ставится):  **Отдай, и ты получишь все.**

1) Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП). Первое предложение **односоставное** (определенно-личное, сказуемое выражено глаголом в повелительном наклонении). Второе предложение **двусоставное**, предикативная основа "ты получишь". В этом случае (при отсутствии общих элементов) запятая ставится в обязательном порядке.

2) Сравнить: **Отдай, и  получишь всё.**

**Здесь также ставится запятая**, но ССП состоит из двух односоставных (определенно-личных) предложений, причем сказуемое выражено **глаголами в разном наклонении.**

Такие сложные предложения следует отличать от  простых предложений с однородными сказуемыми, например: *Возьми книгу и прочитай рассказ*. Здесь сказуемые считаются **однородными**, так как выражены **одной формой глагола**. Запятая не ставится при наличии одиночного союза И.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь всего один вариант, в котором стоит запятая. И запятая стоит верно. 
Вот правило. В сложносочиненном предложении глагольные формы разных наклонений не выступают в роли однородных членов простого предложения. Ср.: ***Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного (Газ.)*** —

Comment: Но ведь здесь второе предложение в ССП является двусоставным, поэтому  запятая ставится в любом случае (нет проблемы различения сложного предложения и предложения с однородными членами).

Comment: @Sharon  (1) Почему здесь НО? (2) Мысль, на мой взгляд, верная, но формулировка неясная.. Я бы переформулировал. Подлежащее  *ты* относится только к сказуемому *получишь*, а это значит, что у нас  именно ССП (первое предложение  односоставное, второе — двусоставное), а не простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, как может показаться на первый взгляд.

Comment: @Sharon А то, что глагольные формы имеют разные наклонения, является вторичным в данном случае (с точки зрения различения сложного предложения и предложения с однородными членами).

Comment: @Sharon Я бы советовал Вам оформить это как ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.